# CGEventRef KeyHandler - Xcode - Mac

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, keyboard, cgeventtap

So I have an app that when you press the numbers on your keyboard on top, it normally types the symbols. 
But with the app it types the numbers.

But if I run it in xcode, everything works fine, but when i open the app outside of xcode it doesn't work.

I have the newest update of mac os x and xcode.

Video:

https://youtu.be/67hRybEmJJY

Can anybody help me please?

```
CGEventRef KeyHandler(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void *refcon)
{
    UniCharCount actualStringLength;
    UniCharCount maxStringLength = 1;
    UniChar chars[3];

CGEventKeyboardGetUnicodeString(event, maxStringLength, &actualStringLength, chars);


NSString *rusLetters1 = @"&";
if (chars[0] == [rusLetters1 characterAtIndex:0]) {
    chars[0] = '1';
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, chars);
    return event;
}
NSString *rusLetters2 = @"é";
if (chars[0] == [rusLetters2 characterAtIndex:0]) {
    chars[0] = '2';
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, chars);
    return event;
}
NSString *rusLetters3 = @"\"";
if (chars[0] == [rusLetters3 characterAtIndex:0]) {
    chars[0] = '3';
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, chars);
    return event;
}
NSString *rusLetters4 = @"'";
if (chars[0] == [rusLetters4 characterAtIndex:0]) {
    chars[0] = '4';
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, chars);
    return event;
}
NSString *rusLetters5 = @"(";
if (chars[0] == [rusLetters5 characterAtIndex:0]) {
    chars[0] = '5';
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, chars);
    return event;
}
NSString *rusLetters6 = @"§";
if (chars[0] == [rusLetters6 characterAtIndex:0]) {
    chars[0] = '6';
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, chars);
    return event;
}
NSString *rusLetters7 = @"è";
if (chars[0] == [rusLetters7 characterAtIndex:0]) {
    chars[0] = '7';
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, chars);
    return event;
}
NSString *rusLetters8 = @"!";
if (chars[0] == [rusLetters8 characterAtIndex:0]) {
    chars[0] = '8';
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, chars);
    return event;
}
NSString *rusLetters9 = @"ç";
if (chars[0] == [rusLetters9 characterAtIndex:0]) {
    chars[0] = '9';
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, chars);
    return event;
}
NSString *rusLetters0 = @"à";
if (chars[0] == [rusLetters0 characterAtIndex:0]) {
    chars[0] = '0';
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, chars);
    return event;
}

//_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

NSString *rusLetters11 = @"&";
if (chars[0] == '1') {
    chars[0] = [rusLetters11 characterAtIndex:0];
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, chars);
    return event;
}
NSString *rusLetters12 = @"é";
if (chars[0] == '2') {
    chars[0] = [rusLetters12 characterAtIndex:0];
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, chars);
    return event;
}
NSString *rusLetters13 = @"\"";
if (chars[0] == '3') {
    chars[0] = [rusLetters13 characterAtIndex:0];
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, chars);
    return event;
}
NSString *rusLetters14 = @"'";
if (chars[0] == '4') {
    chars[0] = [rusLetters14 characterAtIndex:0];
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, chars);
    return event;
}
NSString *rusLetters15 = @"(";
if (chars[0] == '5') {
    chars[0] = [rusLetters15 characterAtIndex:0];
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, chars);
    return event;
}
NSString *rusLetters16 = @"§";
if (chars[0] == '6') {
    chars[0] = [rusLetters16 characterAtIndex:0];
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, chars);
    return event;
}
NSString *rusLetters17 = @"è";
if (chars[0] == '7') {
    chars[0] = [rusLetters17 characterAtIndex:0];
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, chars);
    return event;
}
NSString *rusLetters18 = @"!";
if (chars[0] == '8') {
    chars[0] = [rusLetters18 characterAtIndex:0];
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, chars);
    return event;
}
NSString *rusLetters19 = @"ç";
if (chars[0] == '9') {
    chars[0] = [rusLetters19 characterAtIndex:0];
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, chars);
    return event;
}
NSString *rusLetters10 = @"à";
if (chars[0] == '0') {
    chars[0] = [rusLetters10 characterAtIndex:0];
    CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, chars);
    return event;
}

return event;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    CFMachPortRef      eventTap;
    CGEventMask        eventMask;
    CFRunLoopSourceRef runLoopSource;

    eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGSessionEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, 0, eventMask, KeyHandler, NULL);

    if (!eventTap) {
        exit(1);
    }

    runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0);
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    CGEventTapEnable(eventTap, true);
    CFRunLoopRun();
}
```

Comment: Did you add your app to the allowed apps in System Preferences/Security/Privacy?

Comment: @Willeke yes I added it, it's so strange. I have no idea why it doesn't work

Comment: `eventMask` is undefined?

Comment: @Willeke where should I define it?

Comment: After the declaration and before it is used. Or don't use a variable and put the constant(s) in the function call. `CGEventTapCreate(kCGSessionEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, 0, CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyDown) | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyUp), KeyHandler, NULL)`.

Comment: @Willeke It doesnt work, it give an error when I do it like this.But you can take a look at the project if you want.https://www.dropbox.com/s/50t6d45mi7f746k/Shifter.zip?dl=0    Thanks

Comment: `eventMask` is uninitialized. You have to assign a value to `eventMask` before it is used.

Comment: @Willeke so how can i do that?

Comment: Which event masks do you want to use?

Comment: @Willeke sorry men, :) but i don't realy know what that is. And my english is not on point (i am dutch). But yeah it just needs to ne able to type numbers and not the symbols when you click the buttons on your keyboard. So that & becomes 1, é becomes 2, " becomes 3, ' becomes 4 etc   I hope i am not anouying you ;)

Comment: I mean the fourth parameter of `CGEventTapCreate`. I'll give a working example in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do. There are many ways to calculate the modified character, this is one of them.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (assign) CFMachPortRef myEventTap;
@property (assign) CFRunLoopSourceRef myRunLoopSource;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

CGEventRef KeyHandler(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void *refcon)
{
    // don't modify keys on the numeric keypad
    CGEventFlags flags = CGEventGetFlags(event);
    if (flags & kCGEventFlagMaskNumericPad)
        return event;

    // get the typed character
    UniCharCount actualStringLength;
    UniChar chars[3];
    CGEventKeyboardGetUnicodeString(event, 3, &actualStringLength, chars);

    // uncomment this line to log the typed character, the modifier flags (Shift, Option, etc.) and the key code (number of the key on the keyboard)
    NSLog(@"%C %llX %lld", chars[0], flags, CGEventGetIntegerValueField(event, kCGKeyboardEventKeycode));

    if (actualStringLength == 1) {
        // map the character from string1 to string2 and vice versa
        NSString *string1 = @"&é\"'(§è!çà";
        NSString *string2 = @"1234567890";
        NSString *typedString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:chars length:1];
        // find the index of the typed character in string1
        NSRange range = [string1 rangeOfString:typedString];
        if (range.location != NSNotFound)
            // get the character in string2 at the same index
            chars[0] = [string2 characterAtIndex:range.location];
        else {
            // find the index of the typed character in string2
            range = [string2 rangeOfString:typedString];
            if (range.location != NSNotFound)
                // get the character in string1 at the same index
                chars[0] = [string1 characterAtIndex:range.location];
        }
        // if the character was found, replace the character in the event
        if (range.location != NSNotFound)
            CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, chars);
    }
    return event;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // create an event tap, we want the key down and key up events
    CGEventMask eventMask = CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyDown) | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyUp);
    self.myEventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGSessionEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, kCGEventTapOptionDefault, eventMask, KeyHandler, NULL);
    if (self.myEventTap) {
        // create a runloop source
        self.myRunLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, self.myEventTap, 0);
        // add it to the current run loop
        CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), self.myRunLoopSource, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    }
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // remove the event tap
    if (self.myRunLoopSource) {
        CFRunLoopSourceInvalidate(self.myRunLoopSource);
        CFRelease(self.myRunLoopSource);
    }
    if (self.myEventTap)
        CFRelease(self.myEventTap);
}

@end
```

Comment: it's the same problem with this code, did it work when you did it? i am running os x el capitan.

Comment: ok nevermind, i deleted the app and it's files, and now its working thanks men!